# List of hardware accelerated CSS properties for mobile safari

Tags: css, ios6, hardware-acceleration

I went across change logs of MobileSafari in iOS 6 where it states:

> WebKit no longer always creates hardware-accelerated layers for
>   elements with the -webkit-transform: preserve-3d option. Authors
>   should stop using this option as a way to get hardware acceleration

Does there exist any list of hardware accelerated CSS properties ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

These aspects of your document can be accelerated by the GPU:

- General layout compositing
- CSS3 transitions
- CSS3 3D transforms
- Canvas Drawing
- WebGL 3D Drawing

More on this here http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/speed/html5/

Maybe this article will help toohttp://indiegamr.com/ios6-html-hardware-acceleration-changes-and-how-to-fix-them/

And this one http://mobile.smashingmagazine.com/2012/06/21/play-with-hardware-accelerated-css/

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but It would be great if we would make a list of those css properties.

Answer (score 10):

Paul Lewis & Paul Irish have a really good article about High Performance Animations.

> "We’re going to cut straight to the chase. Modern browsers can animate four things really cheaply: position, scale, rotation and opacity. If you animate anything else, it’s at your own risk, and the chances are you’re not going to hit a *silky smooth 60fps*."

## **4 things a browser can animate cheaply**

**Position** - transform: translate(*n* px, *n* px);

**Scale**    - transform: scale(*n*);

**Rotation** - transform: rotate(*n* deg);

**Opacity** - opacity: *0..1*;

TranslateZ() or Translate3D() may be required.

---

*Source: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/speed/high-performance-animations/*